# RandomAccessFile unexpected behavior for seek and write or write with offset

Tags: java, io

I cannot understand what is the difference between

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
int offset = getOffset();
byte[] dataInBytes = getData();
raf.seek(offset);
raf.write(dataInBytes, 0, getSize())'
```

and

```
...
byte[] dataInBytes = getData();
raf.write(dataInBytes, offset, getSize());
```

I thought seeking and then writing is equivalent to using write function with offset instead of zero. But seems it is not the case.
I do not know what's the difference yet, I just need to pass unit tests, and second version passes unit tests and the first does not.

What is the difference between those two approaches?

Comment: Without any context, it's impossible to answer your question - the "difference between those two approaches" should be pretty obvious from the code - read the Javadocs for those functions.  What is missing is the context you're making those calls from.

Comment: The offset is for the byte[] not the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the JavaDoc of [RandomAccessFile#write(byte[]. int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#write-byte:A-int-int-):

> Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this file.
>   **Parameters**:
>   `b` - the data.
>   `off` - the start offset in the data.
>   `len` - the number of bytes to write.

The offset parameter that you pass into `write(byte[], int, int)` is not an offset into the file, but an offset into the byte array that you pass.

Your first code snippet positions the `RandomAccessFile` at position `offset` and then writes `getSize()` bytes from the beginning of the data array at that position.

Your second code snippets does not change the position within the `RandomAccessFile` (that probably means starting to write at the beginning of the file) and then writes `getSize()` bytes of the data array, beginning with the byte at position `offset` in the byte array.

Answer (score 1):

In the former the offset is into the file you are accessing. In the later it is an offset into the array.